# Mongodb Nested array limt and sort using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting, limit, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi I am newbie to mongodb . i have a document like here

```
  {
    "_id" : "58e46f81c4734559ac8082f0",
    "Name" : "test",
    "Students" : [ 
        {

            "Name" : "A",
            "Marks" : "3"
         }
                  ]
    }
```

i want to apply limit on students array and sortBy Marks using c# mongodb Drivers

please suggest any way to do this .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using AsQueryable

`collection.AsQueryable().Where(predict).SelectMany(Property).OrderByDescending().Take(number)`

Now using this i am able to create mongodb query .it works for me. i am getting required result

Comment: What is the predict? Or Property? Congratulations, you might have won the worst answer award!!

Comment: @Cemal  I don't thik you have used  mongodb with linq in .net . predict would be where condition for ex-: collection.AsQueryable().Where(i=>i.id==10) and property or object is want to get in query result like name etc

Comment: It is not about me understanding per se, but about the guidelines of answering on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the MongoDB.Driver version 2.4:

```
var context = new Context();
var builder = Builders<Thing>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Name, "test"); // Or by Id, etc.
var result = context.ThingCollection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefault();
var students = result.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Marks).Take(limit).ToList();
```

The `students` variable is a list of limited number of students sorted by mark.

**Update**

This also works:

```
var result = context.ThingCollection.Find(filter).Project(x => x.Students.Select(y => y).OrderByDescending(z => z.Marks).Take(3)).ToList();
```

Comment: its in memory processing . i want query that get only required data from database . do not want any in memory processing on result

Comment: Right, i just want portion of nested array